# How this operation is called?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, convolution

This operation is similar to discrete convolution and cross-correlation, but has binomial coefficients:

$$f(n)\star g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f(n-k)g(k) $$

Particularly,

$$a^n\star b^n=(a+b)^n$$

following binomial theorem.

I just wonder if there is a name for such operation and where I can read about its properties.

Comment: To be precise, one should write $(f\star g)(b)$ rather than $f(n)\star g(n)$.  For example, what if $n=5$ and $f(5)=3$ and $g(5)7$.  Would $f(n)\star g(n)$ then be $3\star 7$?  Obviously that's nonsense.

Comment: Composition is distributive against any binary functions. That is $(f\circ w) \star (g \circ w) = (f \star g) \circ w$ for any f,g,w and binary operation $\star$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called a *binomial convolution* in Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics*.  I don't have that text in front of me (but I bet someone here can give you a page number), but here's a reference on the [Fermat's Last Theorem blog](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/10/generating-function-for-bernoulli.html).

It would also be worth checking out Section 2.3 of Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology*.  This is on exponential generating functions.  The property of interest is that if $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are the exponential generating functions of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, respectively, then $F(x)G(x)$ is the exponential generating function of $f(n) \star g(n)$.

(FYI: You can download the second edition of *Generatingfunctionology* from [Wilf's web site](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).)

Comment: Its page 366 in the second edition.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks.  I knew someone would find it quickly. :)

Comment: There is no page 366 in the second edition.

Comment: @IgorRivin: The "binomial convolution" reference is on page 365 of the second edition of *Concrete Mathematics*.  Perhaps you are talking about *Generatingfunctionology*?

Comment: @MikeSpivey Yes, I was, that clears it up!

Answer (score 5):

Remark that one can employ the powerful umbral calculus to compute closed forms for many such **binomial convolutions** of special functions, e.g. from p. 161 of Roman: Umbral Calculus:
[image]

Comment: Note for casual readers: page 17 of the book defines the concept of an "Appell sequence".

Comment: I wonder where can I find a closed form expression of binomial Bell's numbers of higher order? I.e. I need $\sum_{k=0}^{x-1} B_n^x \star B_n^k$

Comment: @MathFacts: You might try posting that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same *binomial convolution* in the following curious setting: consider the shift operator $S(a_n) = (a_{n+1})$
which maps
$(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots) \mapsto (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)$.

It is easy to check that $S$ is a *derivation* of this convolution, that is:
$$ S ((a_n) \star (b_n)) = S (a_n) \star (b_n) + (a_n) \star S(b_n)   $$
just by using Pascal's rule
$ {n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n+1 \choose k-1} $.

This can be used to give a proof of the form of the general solution to a linear recurrence (homogeneous, with constant coefficients): Just repeat the same linear algebra one does to give a proof of the form of the general solution to a linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients, exchanging the derivative operator D, functions and the exponential functions by the shift operator S, sequences and the geometrical sequences.

I have not seen this used elsewhere and I do not know if it has other applications other then the one sketched above.

Comment: It seems this operator works on binomial convolution like a derivative on a product.

Comment: Exactly @Anixx, the above would be the analogous to Leibnitz derivation rule for the shift $S$ under this convolution product, this surprised me!
One can use this to solve linear recurrences very much like linear ODEs: by *characteristic roots* or by the *annihilator method*, which was what I was I looking for when I found this.

Comment: I wrote a paper a few years ago that uses finite differences to evaluate binomial sums.  Since the finite difference is $S(a_n) - a_n$, some of the ideas in there are related to your observation here.  In case you're interested, the paper is [here](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/CombSum.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the article @MikeSpivey, I will take a look!

And Anixx, the analogy with ODE gets better using "Taylor series" $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$.

First, the coeficients of the derivative are given by the shift:
$$
\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n \right)'
= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!} x^n
$$

Second, the coefficients of the product is the binomial convolution:
$$
\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n \right)
\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n!} x^n \right)
= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{((a_n) \star (b_n))_n}{n!} x^n
$$

Answer (score 2):

It corresponds to multiplying exponential generating functions (check *generatingfunctionology*).