# Formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) k$, where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I would like to compute $\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) k$, where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind. Any ideas? It is like I am convolving the Stirling numbers of the second kind with the positive integers. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not a convolution. The convolution would be $\sum_{k=0}^n kS(n,n-k)$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n),$$
where $\varpi(n)$ is the $n$th [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Using generating functions, I prove this and the generalizations
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k^m = \sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i} R(m-i) \varpi(n+i),$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} (-1)^k k^m = \sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i} \varpi(m-i) R(n+i),$$
where $R(n)$ is the $n$th [Rao-Uppuluri-Carpenter number](http://oeis.org/A000587), in the paper "[On Solutions to a General Combinatorial Recurrence](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Spivey/spivey31.pdf)" (*Journal of Integer Sequences* **14** (9), Article 11.9.7, 2011).  See Identities 12 and 13, which are at the very end.  <strike>This paper has been submitted for publication, and I am still waiting on referee reports.</strike>

I don't know whether these results are new, but I had not seen them before.  (They are not the main point of the paper.)

---

**Added**: Here are some additional derivations for $\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n)$.  They are shorter than the one needed in the paper for the more general result.

**First**: Use the recurrence for the Stirling numbers of the second kind.  (Due to OP - see comments.)

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n+1 \atop k\right\} - \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k-1\right\} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left\{ n+1 \atop k\right\} - \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\}  =\varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n).$$

**Second**: Use [Bell polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) $B_n(x)$.

It is known that $\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k \right\} x^k = B_n(x)$ (Eq. 14 on the linked page), $\frac{d}{dx} B_n(x) = \frac{B_{n+1}(x)}{x} - B_n(x)$ (Eq. 16), and $B_n(1) = \varpi(n)$ (Eq. 1).  Thus

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \frac{d}{dx} \left.\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} x^k \right|_{x=1} = \frac{d}{dx} \left. B_n(x) \right|_{x=1} = \frac{B_{n+1}(1)}{1} - B_n(1) = \varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n).$$

**Third**: Use the double generating function for the Stirling numbers of the second kind (see, for example, *Concrete Mathematics*, 2nd edition, p. 351)
$$\sum_{n,k \geq 0} \left\{ n \atop k\right\} w^k \frac{z^n}{n!} = e^{w(e^z-1)}.$$
(The right-hand side is actually the exponential generating function for the Bell polynomials, so this derivation is a variation on the second one.)
Differentiating both sides with respect to $w$ and then letting $w = 1$ yields the exponential generating function (egf) for the sum in question:
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k \right) \frac{z^n}{n!} = e^{e^z-1} e^z - e^{e^z-1}.$$

It is known that $e^{e^z-1}$ is the egf for the Bell numbers.  Since $e^z$ is the egf of the infinite sequence of $1$'s, and multiplication of exponential generating functions corresponds to [binomial convolutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/how-this-operation-is-called/8714#8714) of the sequences in question, this means

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \varpi(k) - \varpi(n).$$
Finally, $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \varpi(k) = \varpi(n+1)$ is a [well-known identity for the Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Properties_of_Bell_numbers), so we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n).$$

---

**Added much later:**

**Fourth**: A combinatorial argument.  The Stirling number $\left\{ n \atop k \right\}$ counts the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty subsets, and the Bell number $\varpi(n)$ is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into any number of subsets.  Thus $k \left\{ n \atop k \right\}$ is the number of ways to partition $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty subsets and then add an element $n+1$ to one of these $k$ subsets.  Summing over all values of $k$ would then give the number of ways to partition a set of $n+1$ elements into any number of nonempty subsets, except for the partitions in which element $n+1$ is in a subset by itself.  But this number is $\varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n)$, as the number of partitions of $n+1$ elements in which $n+1$ is in a subset by itself is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ elements.  Putting all this together, we get 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{ n \atop k\right\} k = \varpi(n+1) - \varpi(n).$$

Comment: Thank you @MikeSpivey ! hope you get good reviews from the referees.

Comment: @MikeSpivey I think there is an even simpler proof of the previous identity using the recurrence of the Stirling numbers of the second kind $\left\{{n+1\atop k}\right\} = \left\{{n\atop k-1}\right\} +k \left\{{ n \atop k }\right\}$ . And this is because the right part of the recurrence contains exactly what you want to prove (you have to sum also). But I think summation is not a problem... the steps are straight forward. I wonder if your formula in your paper could work for negative $m$ in the Rao-Uppuluri-Carpenter formula (unfortunately these numbers are not defined for negative integers). T

Comment: (oops, in the conversion process pebox11's query got chopped off. Here's the end of it after the letter `T`). This is because what if someone would like to find $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{S(n,k)}{k}$ ?? where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind?

Comment: @pebox11: as you can see, I've merged your duplicate account into the one you originally used to ask this question. Please consider registering your account: it makes it more 'portable' so that such account duplication can be avoided in the future. I've also moved your query, which is properly a comment to Mike's answer, to here.

Comment: @pebox11: You're absolutely right; that's a much simpler proof.  I'm not sure about the $m = -1$ case; perhaps the RUC numbers could be generalized to negative values of $m$.

Comment: Bleh, if I had the time, I'd go through all the questions/answers involving Stirling numbers and make sure they all use $\left[ n \atop k\right]$ and $\left\{ n \atop k\right\}$ ... anyway, I love how Bell and Stirling are so intricately related!