# Simplify $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n} \frac{a^{N-n}}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, summation, power-series

Simplify the following expression
$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n} \frac{a^{N-n}}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x), $$
where $a$ is a real number and $f(x)$ is an analytic real function.
What is $\lim_n S_n$? Is there a simple intuitive meaning to it?

I only found formulas which come close but not quite what I need:

Without the $n!$ in the denominator, the expression can be simpified using the  [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n} a^{N-n} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) =e^{-ax}\frac{d^N}{dx^N}\left[ e^{ax} f(x)\right].$$
Without the binomial coefficient the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion of $f(x)$ around $x$ gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{a^{N-n}}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) =a^N f\left(x+a^{-1}\right).$$

**EDIT**:
With an extra set of parentheses
$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n}a^{N-n}\right]\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)  \right] = (1+a)^N f(x+1) $$
On the other hand
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{N!}\frac{d^N}{dz^N}\sum_n A_n z^n \sum_m B_m z^m = 
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{N!}\frac{d^N}{dz^N} \sum_{N} \sum_{n} A_{N-n}B_n z^N  = \sum_n A_{N-n}B_n$$
so combining the above two 
$$\sum_n \binom{N}{n} \frac{a^{N-n}}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{N!}\frac{d^N}{dz^N}\left[ (1+az)^N f(x+z)\right] $$
Is this right? Is there a simpler expression?

Answer (score 2):

If your function $f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i,$ then 
$$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \binom{N}{n} a^{N-n} a_n.$$ This is a [*binomial convolution*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/how-this-operation-is-called),
So the Exponential Generating function of the sequence $S_N$ equals $\exp(a x) g(z),$ where $g(z)$ is the exponential generating function of of the $a_i.$

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely useful. Is there a name for the map $f(z) \rightarrow g(z)$, i.e ``the exponential generating function of a sequence corresponding to an ordinary generating function $f(x)$''? Does this map have common applications?

Comment: I am lost at the first step. Following your definition, $$S_N = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}a^{N-n}a_{k+n}x^{k}\,.$$ This is not what you have written. Are you considering only the $x=0$ limit? Or are you denoting my function $(1+az)^N f(x+z)$ by $f(z)$ and manipulating my last identity?

Comment: Yes, I probably confused matters too much. see the simplified version.

Comment: Shouldn't I need an extra $1/N^{N-n}$ for that to work? In that case $S'_N \equiv \sum_n \binom{N}{n} \frac{a^{N-n}}{N^{N-n}n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)$ and so $$\sum_N S'_N z^N = \sum_N \frac{z^N}{N!} \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^N}{dz^N}\left[ \left(1+\frac{az}{N}\right)^N f(x+z)\right] = \sum_N \frac{z^N}{N!} \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^N}{dz^N}\left[ e^{az} f(x+z)\right] = e^{az} f(x+z) $$ but again I have $z$ instead of $x$ in the exponential and this is an ordinary generating function, so I might be missing your point. Can you elaborate more?